# How do I add a name to several columns?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to assign a name (like John) to the columns "Season_1" and "Season_2 of the following DataFrame:

```
             Season_1  Season_2
Wins         151       120
Losses       124       110
```

So that it should look like that:

```
             John
             Season_1  Season_2
Wins         151       120
Losses       124       110
```

This can probably be solved with a MultiIndex. However, I can't seem to find out how that works when there is already an existing DataFrame.

I have created this DataFrame with this code:

```
wins = {'Wins': (151, 120)}

losses = {'Losses': (124, 110)}

dict_all = {**wins, **losses}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_all, orient='index', columns=['Season_1', 'Season_2'])
```

Later I would like to combine several DataFrames so that I would get something like this. I would use pandas.merge() for that:

```
             John                Adam
             Season_1  Season_2  Season_1  Season_2
Wins         151       120       111       110
Losses       124       110       102       110
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a column level

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['John'], df.columns])

        John
        Season_1    Season_2
Wins    151         120
Losses  124         110
```

Follow-up question1:  "John" for Seasons_1 and "Adam" for Season_2

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('John', 'Season_1'), ('Adam', 'Season_2')])
```

Follow-up question2: 5 columns ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") and assign the level "One" to "A", "B", "C" and the level "Two" to "D", "E".

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('One', 'A'),('One', 'B'),('One', 'C'), ('Two', 'D'),('Two', 'E')])
```

Comment: Thank you! What if you would want "John" for Seasons_1 and "Adam" for Season_2?

Comment: You can try df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('John', 'Season_1'), ('Adam', 'Season_2')])

Comment: This works, thank you. One more question: What if I had 5 columns ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") and I want to assign the level "One" to "A", "B", "C" and the level "Two" to "D", "E". from_tuples does not work. What function would I use in this case?

Comment: You would use df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('One', 'A'),('One', 'B'),('One', 'C'), ('Two', 'D'),('Two', 'E')]) in that case

Comment: Here is another follow-up question (based on the 2. question): What if I had a list ["A", "B", "C"] and list ["D", "E"]. How could I assign the first list to level "One" and the second list to level "Two"? from_tuples works perfectly, but writing 5 times the level name is annoying..

Comment: Here is the solution:
    index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['One'], list1]
    index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Two'], list2]

    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.join(index1, index2, how='outer')

Comment: I had already updated my post with solution to follow up question 2